# RegExp javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Объясните, пожалуйста, в чем у меня ошибка. Не особо шарю в регулярных выражениях)

Хочу сделать проверку на введенные данные для двух полей: дата рождения и годы обучения. И так получается, что правильными данными считаются любые числа, записанные любым образом.

http://pastebin.com/XW1dRfJ5

Comment: Сначала прочтите [вот это](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ладно. Вот так?    
http://jsfiddle.net/jsc2rpyb/

Comment: Верите не верите, но ни одна из предложенных вами регулярок не подошла) Пробовал на том же jsfiddle, не работает. Я пробовал сделать одну регулярку для даты рождения и периода обучения, чтобы удостовериться в корректной работе, но результат не радует.

Comment: Если кому интересно, то ошибка была вот тут:  
/^(19{1}[0-9]{2}|2{1}[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2})-(19{1}[0-9]{2}|2{1}[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2})$/  
А до этого было так: 
/^(19{1}[0-9]{2}|2{1}0|1{1}[0-9]{2})-(19{1}[0-9]{2}|2{1}0|1{1}[0-9]{2})$/
Изменил 0|1 на [0-1]

Answer (score 1):

```
\d{4}-\d[4] //2000-2010

\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2} //09.03.01
```

Comment: Старайтесь писать более детальные ответы. Можно объяснить путь решения, указать на конкретные ошибки, привести ссылки с более подробным разбором проблемы и т. п.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю для проверки введенной даты рождения использовать такую регулярку

```
/^(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\.(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\.(19[0-9]{2}|200[0-9]|201[0-5])$/
```

А для проверки периода обучения такую

```
/^(19[0-9]{2}|200[0-9]|201[0-5])-(19[0-9]{2}|200[0-9]|201[0-5])$/
```

P.S. Вероятно, лучше использовать возможности html input и его атрибутов type
 (date и number), min и max.